# How to run tensorflow 2.0 model inference in Java?

Tags: tensorflow, deployment, deep-learning

I have a Java application that use my old tensorflow models. I used to convert the .h5 weights and .json model into a frozen graph in .pb.

I used a similar code than in this github https://github.com/amir-abdi/keras_to_tensorflow.

But this code but it's not compatible with tf 2.0 model.

I couldn't find any other resources.

Is it even possible?

Thank you :)